# What does 'innodb_buffer_pool_reads' and 'innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests' actually mean?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

Mysql version: 5.7.18 (Innodb)

I have a table with the following specification

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `dummybigint10` (
  `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so.',
  `num1` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num2` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num3` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num4` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num5` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num6` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num7` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num8` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num9` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num10` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2163184 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Row count**: 1049088

The B+ tree of this table has 19104 leaf nodes (out of which 19075 used) and 20 internal nodes (out of which 20 is used). [Thanks to innodb_ruby project]

I fired a query to cause a full table scan as follows:

```
select count(*) from dummybigint10 where num9 is not null;
```

I observed for the values in '**innodb_buffer_pool_reads** from performance_schema.

Observed values are:

**innodb_buffer_pool_reads: 98**

Some resource available online say that, '**innodb_buffer_pool_reads**' is the number of pages which are loaded by Innodb from disk, which in my case , a full table scan on the given table has to cause at least **19104** but the actual value reported by Innodb is **98**. I think that resource is misleading the interpretation of **innodb_buffer_pool_reads**. Can any one explain what does **innodb_buffer_pool_reads** actually mean?

Comment: Restart mysqld and run the test again.  This will force all the reads to come from disk, not just the buffer_pool (cache).  Were there 19K read _requests_?

Comment: While you are at it, do `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Inno%';` and `SELECT name, type, count, FORMAT(avg_count, 1) AS per_second, comment FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics WHERE name LIKE '%innodb%';`

Comment: @RickJames can you please explain what is innodb-buffer-pool-reads ? Because, I got diffrent explanation from different source.

Comment: @RickJames the above measurement were taken after mysql was restarted. Hence no buffer pool cache.

Comment: @RickJames i have observed innodb-page-read which is approximately 19k. Can u explain me what does the values in innodb-buffer-pool-read means?

Comment: You are talking about `Innodb_pages_read`?  19K since the server started.  Divide by `Uptime` to get something useful.  10/sec is about the "median" value; 1000/sec is high, and probably implies SSD.  The manual is rather ambiguous:  "The number of pages read from the InnoDB buffer pool by operations on InnoDB tables."

Comment: Meanings:  https://www.facebook.com/notes/mysql-at-facebook/innodb-disk-io-counters-in-show-status/445139830932/

Comment: Where in `performance_schema` did you find the value?

Comment: @RickJames performance_schema.global_status table

Comment: Ah, yes, that table moved from I_S to P_S.  5.7 had it both places; it is gone from I_S in 8.0.  8.0 has a _lot_ of changes.

Comment: @RickJames yeah can u correct me if i were wrong ... innodb-buffer-pool-read denotes the number of times mysql/innodb has contacted the storage device for data which may be single page or may be an extent ..

Comment: That sounds "close".  The Facebook link said more than anything I have ever found.  Yet it was still vague.  What is your goal?  I would like a reliable way to measure disk activity for a single query.  This `STATUS` seems at least close.  The `Handler%` values are quite good at the 'row' level, but not 'disk' level.